# How to redirect from different pages, if I access controller from different pages?

Tags: php, laravel

I have PostsController@destroy and if user is on some page programm should redirect to index after deleting. If user on dashboard page it should redirect to dashboard. How can I do it? Here is destroy func in PostsController

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->delete();
    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Post removed!');
}
```

Comment: `redirect()->back()` or simply `back()`

Comment: But how to make if statement?

Comment: What if statement? It will just go back where the request originated... **back** means **back**.

Answer (score 0):

i would do it with the following:

```
return back()->with('success', 'Post removed!');
```

Comment: But I want something like that:
if(on page dashboard) return back()->with('success', 'Post removed!');
else return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Post removed!');

Comment: then you have get the current Route name in Laravel. 

 \Route::currentRouteName() and check in your if statement on which route you are.